# Static page does not show my posts

Tags: posts, theme-development, homepage

I have a home.php and an index.php.

Wanting my home.php (set as static) to display 3 grid style showing 3 posts.

This is my current code.

```
<?php
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=4'); 

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
echo '<ul>'; 
while ( $the_query->have_post(); 
       echo'<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
       }
       echo '</ul>'; 
       } else {
           // no post found
       }
       */ Restore original post data */
       wp_rest_postdata();

    `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is the code I have on one of my Website inside the footer, this basically get's the 3 latest posts and displays `the_title` you can change this to show `the_excerpt`.

```
<?php // news posts loop begins here
    $newsPosts = new WP_Query('page=blog&posts_per_page=3');

    if ($newsPosts->have_posts()) : 
    while ($newsPosts->have_posts()) : $newsPosts->the_post(); ?>

    <!-- Blogs -->
    <div class="post-item">
        <!-- This is where you can insert the excerpt -->
        <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
    </div>

    <!-- ./Blogs -->
    <?php endwhile;
    else :

    // fallback no content message here
        endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: thank you @CoderSte - IT WORKED!!!! But it's not appearing, stylistically, how I want it to.  Does this mean that I need to now work in CSS?

Comment: Yeah just style the `div` element